# Dedicated SQL Pool - Can we create Copy Activity Tasks in SQL?

Tags: azure-synapse

At the moment, we have a pipeline to bring in data from On Premise SQL Server to Data Lakes to the Azure Dedicated SQL Pool. There's about 100 tables and it's very tedious (even using a For Each Activity) to manage/edit the pipeline in the Synapse workspace.

Is there a way to do this process using pure SQL? I did see some syntax for COPY INTO and CTAS.

Comment: Could you please provide your approach?

Comment: Please update your question to detail what aspects of your current pipeline is tedious ?  Perhaps you are manually defining each table to get copied by hardcoding the table into your ForEach activity ?   once you supply such an update we can help out ... and yes the synapse pipeline web UI is terrible in many ways however I have crafted a pipeline to en mass copy many table where I avoid any such hardcode ... we await your update

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK cop data activity is an activity in azure data factory or azure synapse to copy data from source to destination, we cannot create it using SQL script. But if you want to copy data from on-premises to SQL dedicated pool first save the data as flat file using BCP or SSIS and upload it azure data lake or copy them using ADF pipeline to data lake. In synapse dedicated pool create scoped credential for data lake access using below code

```
create  database scoped credential creds
with  identity ='Access-key',
secret ='accessKey'
```

create external data source below code:

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL  DATA SOURCE [ExternalDataSource1] WITH  
(
TYPE = HADOOP,
LOCATION = 'abfss://container@storageAcc.dfs.core.windows.net',   
credential = creds    
)
```

[image]

Create External file format using below code:

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL  FILE FORMAT [ExternalFileFormat] WITH
(
   FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT
)
```

Create a external table with external data source and file format
code:

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL  TABLE [schema].[externalTablename]
(
   <requred columns>
)
WITH
(
  LOCATION = '<fileName>',
  DATA_SOURCE = [ExternalDataSourceName],
  FILE_FORMAT = [ExternalFileFormatName]
)
```

[image]

Crate a new table and copy extarnal table data to it using CTAS

```
CREATE  TABLE [schema].[tableName]
WITH
(
DISTRIBUTION = REPLICATE,
CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
AS
SELECT * FROM [schema].[externalTablename]]
OPTION (LABEL = 'CTAS : Load [schema].[externalTablename]');
```

It will copy successfully. If you want more information regarding CTAS you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/load-data-wideworldimportersdw).

[image]

But we can use this approach for less number of tables for more number tables like 100 of tables we need to create a stored procedure by following above procedure and execute that in Azure data factory or logic apps tools to control it. But it will become more complex to do that. you can create pipeline and use bulk insert option in copy data activity in Azure data factory to copy more number of tables from on-premises to sql dedicated pool using below pipeline

[image]

Use self-hosted integration run time to connect with on-premises sql server. Here is pipeline JSON

```
 {
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "SqlServerSource",
                        "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT  TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND  TABLE_SCHEMA= 'dbo'",
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                        "partitionOption": "None"
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "SqlServerTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "SqlServerSource",
                                    "sqlReaderQuery": {
                                        "value": "SELECT * FROM [@{item().TABLE_SCHEMA}].[@{item().TABLE_NAME}]",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                                    "partitionOption": "None"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "SqlDWSink",
                                    "preCopyScript": "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'  ",
                                    "writeBehavior": "Insert",
                                    "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false,
                                    "tableOption": "autoCreate",
                                    "disableMetricsCollection": false
                                },
                                "enableStaging": true,
                                "stagingSettings": {
                                    "linkedServiceName": {
                                        "referenceName": "AzureDataLakeStorage1",
                                        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                                    },
                                    "path": "synfiles"
                                },
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "SqlServerTable1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "AzureSynapseAnalyticsTable1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "DWSchema": {
                                            "value": "@item().TABLE_NAME",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "DWTableName": {
                                            "value": "@item().TABLE_SCHEMA",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```